# is there any way to ensure VT-x is both supported and enabled in Lenovo ThinkStation P500

Tags: virtualbox, bios, virtualization, lenovo-desktop-computer

Scenario ... i am trying to run windows DataCentre 2008 64-bit under vBox 5.1.26 on a ThinkStation P500.

regardless whether VT-d (sic) is enabled, Windows 10 Pro Task Manager shows virtualization is enabled.

the only virtualization option that i can find in the Legacy BIOS is for VT-d.

in ALL combinations of settings i tried, vBox claimed VT-x (sic) was not available.

Note that 32-bit windows DataCentre 2008 installed without no issues under vBox.

Please note that i have also posted on vBox forum:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=84301

OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Version    10.0.10586 Build 10586
LENOVO  System Model    30A6003MUS; System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  LENOVO_MT_30A6_BU_LENOVO_FM_ThinkStation P500
Processor   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1607 v3 @ 3.10GHz, 3100 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   LENOVO A4KT53AUS, 2014-10-22
SMBIOS Version  2.8
Embedded Controller Version 14.30
BIOS Mode   Legacy
PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB
A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.

Comment: RESOLVED thank you to *eric* [Lenovo forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkStation-Workstations/does-P500-workstation-support-VT-x/m-p/3772725) ... removing Hyper-V freed up VT-x

Comment: also very useful is this article:  [I have a 64bit host, but can't install 64bit guests](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=62339)